# Is it possible to keep the user data with a smartphone that boots to the data wipe menu?

Tags: recovery-mode, battery, charging, boot, miui

My smartphone turns on without passing the OS loading screen, **then loads the recovery menu (Redmi-Recovery 3.0)**. I can't turn off the device, I tried waiting for the battery to run off, charge it and turn it on again, it still can't boot properly. In fact, **it won't stay turned off** even when the charger is first inserted after the battery has been depleted.

The phone is a Xiaomi Redmi Note 9, **OS is MIUI** (not sure which version), the menu items are: system reboot (reboots and gets back to this screen), connect to PC with the Mi Assistant (I tried to use the Mi PC Suite, but the device isn't detected, I guess because USB debugging is off on the device), wipe memory (I guess this wipes the system partition along with all the files).

I think my only option is is to wipe everything and hope that it will then boot properly. I was wondering **if there is a way to only "restore" the operating system, without touching the user's data** (I think I've seen something of this sort both on Linux ans Windows before).

I am also concerned about the phone not staying turned off (I am a bit scared the **battery controller** is gone for some reason).

*Since I have a backup phone that I can use I'm planning of waiting on this question for a week or so and see of something comes up.*

Comment: no, there is no way. because the whole system is read-only, factory reset will just reset userdata nothing more

Comment: btw seems power button is stuck or is wet

Comment: @alecxs it seems something like that (probably something got wet), but it has already been 48 hours

Comment: A factory reset literally deletes the contents of the user data partition, if you found a way to "reset" and leave the user data intact, you didn't really do anything.

Comment: guess the volume button is wet, too. that's why it boots into recovery. no need for factory reset, just wait a week